# How to get value from radio button stored on modal using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

```
<!-- Custom Modals -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="con-close-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog"> 
                    <div class="modal-content"> 
                        <div class="modal-header"> 
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="con-close-modalLabel">Tambah Jadwal Shift</h4> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="modal-body"> 
                            <form action="tjadwal.php" method="post" id="insert_form">
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="nomor_shift" value="<?php echo $d['nomor_shift']; ?>">
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="nama" class="control-label">Nama</label> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama" placeholder="Nama" required=""> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="jabatan" class="control-label">Jabatan</label> 
                                        <select class="form-control" id="jabatan" name="jabatan">
                                            <option>SNOC</option>
                                            <option>Control Center</option>
                                        </select> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="tanggal" class="control-label">Tanggal</label> 
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tanggal" name="tanggal" required=""> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="shift_mulai" class="control-label">Jam mulai shift</label> 
                                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="shift_mulai" name="shift_mulai" required=""> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="shift_selesai" class="control-label">Jam selesai shift</label> 
                                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="shift_selesai" name="shift_selesai" required=""> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin"> 
                                        <label for="keterangan_shift" class="control-label">Keterangan</label> 
                                        <textarea class="form-control autogrow" id="keterangan_shift" name="keterangan_shift" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 104px;" required=""></textarea>
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                            
                        </div> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <strong class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Status</strong>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="status" name="status" value="BELUM JAM SHIFT">
                                        Belum jam shift
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="status" name="status" value="SEDANG JAM SHIFT">
                                        Sedang jam shift
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer"> 
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button> 
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light">Tambah Jadwal</button>
                            </form> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

```
JQUERY
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.tombolTambahJadwal').on('click', function() {
        $('#con-close-modalLabel').html('Tambah Jadwal Shift');
        $('.modal-footer button[type=submit]').html('Tambah Jadwal');
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset(); 
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.tampilModalUbah', function() {
        
        $('#con-close-modalLabel').html('Ubah Jadwal Shift');
        $('.modal-footer button[type=submit]').html('Ubah Jadwal');
        $('.modal-body form').attr('action', 'ubahJadwal.php');

        var nomor_shift = $(this).data("id");
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "idJadwal.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { nomor_shift : nomor_shift},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#nama').val(data.nama);
                $('#jabatan').val(data.jabatan);
                $('#tanggal').val(data.tanggal);
                $('#shift_mulai').val(data.shift_mulai);
                $('#shift_selesai').val(data.shift_selesai);
                $('#keterangan_shift').val(data.keterangan_shift);
                $('#status').val(data.status);
                $('#nomor_shift').val(data.nomor_shift);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: What radio button do you want?

Comment: retrieve radio button value when modal edit is run

Comment: value $('#status').val(data.status); doesn't appear, that is the radio button

Comment: You have multiple elements with with the same id `status`, ID must be unique

Comment: id status is taken from modal

Comment: Does not matter, you cant have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: I just want, when the modal edit is executed, the radio value is checked